# Yii compare suffix of domains

Tags: php, yii, conditional-statements, criteria, dataprovider

I need to compare suffix of domains using yii `CActiveDataProvider`

somthing like: display all domains with suffix of .com `where google.com = .com`

for example i am trying this (but both of them not working):

```
'criteria'=>array(    
'condition' => 'domain=:id', 
    'params' => array(':id' => '.com' ),
)
```

or

```
 'criteria'=>array(
        'condition' => "strstr(domain, '.') = .com", 
)
```

what i need to do to get it works?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL `LIKE` syntax

```
'condition' => "domain LIKE CONCAT('%', :id)",
'params' = array('id' => '.com')
```